# Resizing a grid

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

so i have this grid, and i want to make it resizable horizontally

```
<div id="grid">
        <div class="editor-container" id="editor-container">
            <!-- Ensure each textarea has a unique ID -->
            <textarea class="editor" id="htmlEditor"><!--Your initial HTML content here-->
            <b>Hello World!</b></textarea>
            <textarea class="editor" id="jsEditor" style="display: none;"><!--Your initial JS content here--></textarea>
            <textarea class="editor" id="cssEditor" style="display: none;">  body, html {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                font-family:'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
            }
            </textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="divider"> </div>
        <div class="output-container">
            <iframe id="output"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

how do i make it resizable so that i can drag the divider and have it resize and be responsive?

i tried to use mouse down events but it would only work when dragging to the left, and when i dragged to the right it would disconnect unless i dragged VERY slowly

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)